# How can I play an online video in full screen AND type in a text editor at the same time?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, editing, silverlight

I watch instructional videos that play in Silverlight such as the ones at http://windowsclient.net/learn.

I watch them in **full screen** on my **left** monitor.

While the video is playing, I want to be able to **type notes** in a text editor on my **right** monitor.

However, as soon as I press a key, the video **exits** full screen mode.

**How can I force the Silverlight player to stay in full screen mode even as I type in another application?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to do this.  Despite the addition of things like AreoSnap in Win7; windows still doesn't handle handle dual monitors well in all instances.   Full screen applications only working when they've got system focus is the most painful example.  IIRC the latest version of WMP on Win7 does what you want it to do; but as a sole exception to the default behavior I suspect it's a case of the WMP team bludgeoning their way around an OS limitation vs a native way to get proper behavior being added.

Without support from the Windows Team I suspect the best we'll be able to get anytime soon would be for the plugin/browser makers to create a "maximize video to tab" feature that would play in the entirety of the tabs space, while hiding the menu/status/address bars to get a pseudo-full screen effect while still running as a normal mode application.

Comment: I heard on a podcast that the Silverlight team is currently fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Dexpot" (Windows 7). This is similar to Ubuntu's multiple Workspace.

http://www.dexpot.de/

Answer (score 0):

> Make your Text editor into always TOP

Use a tool called: [Always Top](http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm)

[image]

Comment: I installed Always Top and although it works per se (keeps applications on top) it doesn't solve the full-screen-with-two-monitor problem: I put the video into full screen in a browser (tried FF / IE) on the left monitor, then in the right monitor, I've got my editor (tried PSPad / Notepad), but as soon as I type in the editor, the video goes into non-full-screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

This little trick sometimes works for me depending on what I am doing. For example it worked last night when I was talking to some people in IRC using putty and watching NCIS on CBS'es web site.

The trick: 
-Make video full screen
-click on text editor
-repeat until video stays full screen and editor takes focus. It normally takes a few times.

This is not guaranteed to work.

I also think there is a way to get silverlight to no leave full screen that is actually supported by MS but I can not find it. I must have made it up in my memory. =P

Answer (score 0):

Here your solution, you need to edit System.Windows.dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189023%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: I don't see any mention of System.Windows.dll where that link goes to.