# Keep silverlight video in full screen in a dual monitor configuration

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight video playing in the second monitor attached to my laptop. I want to work on my laptop screen and want silverlight video to remain in full screen mode.

Is there some configuration change i need to do on my laptop to make this work?

Comment: There's [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/ba12941f-6042-4778-bd96-821c7f2b40ae/silverlight-exits-fullscreen-upon-mouse-or-keyboard-activity-within-other-screen?forum=silverlighthosting) about the same, but no answer or a workaround. In [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/69982/how-can-i-play-an-online-video-in-full-screen-and-type-in-a-text-editor-at-the-s?rq=1) it was concluded that there is no fix for this.